# Pushing A UIViewController With A UINavigationController In A Tab Bar Application (iOS)

Tags: ios, xcode, uiviewcontroller, uinavigationcontroller

I have a tab bar application.

I added a UINavigationController as a tab. I set a RootViewController as "ContactViewController." I have a button that I want to click to go to "EmailFormViewController."

I've used the method to push the view controller:

```
-(IBAction)goToEmailForm:(id)sender{
    EmailFormViewController *evc = [[EmailFormViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"EmailFormViewController" bundle:nil];
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:evc animated:YES];
}
```

I've attached it to the UIButton on my ViewController. It should work but I'm assuming the problem has something to do with it being in a Tab Based Application?

The error that I get is an EXC_BAD_ACCESS which I know is related to releasing something when it doesn't need to be released or something along those lines. This doesn't happen until I click on the button though and I haven't released anything in this method so I'm confused as to why that would happen. Thanks.

Comment: Could be a problem with a dangling pointer if the parent VC is being unloaded.

Comment: Just to clarify, is the tabBarController set as the rootViewController for your window?  ContactViewController is set as the rootViewController of the navigation controller, right?

Comment: I don't believe the parent VC is being unloaded after I switch views. Can't seem to figure out what it could be (still debugging in different ways)...